# Not able to add an untracked git submodule for commit

Tags: git, github

I maintain my dotfiles setup on Github: https://github.com/ronakg/dotfiles

I use Pathogen to maintain the vim plugins and add them as git submodules to my repo.

Today I added [vim-startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify) as submodule, and I'm committed the change. However it still shows up as untracked file.

I've tried `git add -A` but that didn't work either.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   vim/bundle/vim-startify (untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: You might be misled by the message ``untracked content``. Actually, it means that the submodule is tracked but that its folder contains one or more untracked files, possibly things that have been generated / temporary files, etc... run ``git submodule foreach git status`` to see which files are untracked in all your submodules.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find the untracked files using `git submodule foreach git status`. Please post this as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be misled by the message `(untracked content)`. Actually, it means that the submodule is tracked but that its folder contains one or more untracked files, possibly things that have been generated / temporary files, etc...

To see which files are untracked in all your submodules, run

```
git submodule foreach git status
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into the submodule and sort out its state - the untracked content is in there, not in your parent repo.